# How to customize file_picker UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, picker, customizing

I find it difficult to customize the UI of the file picker. I want to implement a picker with my own new UI rather than a native picker. What should I do?

waiting for a good answer!
I'm not good at English, so I got help from a translator. thank you for reading.

https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_wechat_assets_picker
Is it possible to customize with this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `photo_manager` plugin to get all the photos and make your own file picker, but there is no way to modify the `file_picker` ui as it calls native file pickers directly.

Comment: thanks you so much!!!

It's a pity that you can't customize the file picker's ui.

Comment: No worries, `flutter_wechat_assets_picker` uses `photo_manager`to make his own ui so don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [file_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/file_manager) plugin it support android and linux by the time this answer was written .

[image]